# MySQL Join Query for With Multiple Columns

Tags: mysql, join

I have a question that I think is simple enough but I seem to be having some trouble with it.

I have two tables. Each table has the exact same rows.

I am trying to perform a join on the two tables with the following query:

```
SELECT t1.`* FROM `person` as t1 
      JOIN `person_temp` as t2 
      on t1.`date` = t2.`date` 
      and t1.`name` = t2.`name` 
      and t1.`country_id`= t2.`country_id`
```

The point of this query is to find all of the rows in t1 that match t2 where the combination of date,name, and country_id are the same (those three columns combined make a record unique). i don't think this query is correct for what I am trying to do because if I have the same exact data in both tables I am getting a much larger number of matches back.

Any ideas on how to edit this query to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: please post you code and table structure in sqlfiddle that we can solve problem.

Comment: This should be correct, unless you have duplicates in the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `join`.  Use `exists`:

```
SELECT t1.`*
FROM `person` t1
where exists (select 1
              from `person_temp` as t2 
              where t1.`date` = t2.`date` 
                and t1.`name` = t2.`name` 
                and t1.`country_id`= t2.`country_id`
             );
```

For performance, you want a composite index on `person_temp(date, name, country_id)` (the columns can be in any order).